# Load file in different directory

Tags: java

I want to load xml configuration file located in different directory.

The location of the files is:

```
<location_dir>/jar_file.jar
<location_dir>/xml_file.xml
```

The files are located in different directories which are located into one main directory. The different part is that I want want to sue the same directory structure on many operating systems.

I managed to create this code:

```
public class SeparatorTest
{
    private static SettingsDataObject settingsData;

    public void loadXMLFile() throws JAXBException
    {

        try
        {

            // File location by default     ../conf/xmlfile.xml
            settingsData = unmarshal(".." + File.separator + "conf" + File.separator + "xmlfile.xml");

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I want to ask is this example universal for every OS?

Comment: As long as you use `File.separator` it is universal example.

Comment: How I can improve the code?

Comment: can't say, don't know what does unmarshal method